# Can not redirect after login

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

The code verifies  username and password and then compare the inserted data with stored data in database if they are same then redirect user to profile, but could not figure out why the code here does not do that as expected!

```
com.CommandText = "select [id], [username],[password], [type] FROM [users] WHERE [username] =@username AND [password]= @pass";
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", UserName.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", Password.Text);
//  conn.Open();
SqlDataReader rd = com.ExecuteReader();
if (rd.Read())
    {

 var _id = rd["id"].ToString();
 var _type = rd["type"].ToString();
 var _username = rd["username"].ToString();
 FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(

           1,
           _id,
           DateTime.Now,
           DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1),
           true,
           _type + "." + _username,
           FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
        string hashed_ticket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hashed_ticket);

        if (ticket.IsPersistent) cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        // Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Profile.aspx");

        if (_type == "admin")
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/UserProfile.aspx");

        }

    }

    else
    {
        lb.Text = "invalid  username or password!";

    }
    rd.Close();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: When you run through the the code with break points does the redirect line get called?

Comment: it does not get called!

Comment: My hunch is that _type is not equal to admin.

Comment: _type is equal to admin when run through break points

Comment: it's case sensitive, ADMIN != admin, aDmIn != admin, Admin != admin

Comment: Also you are doing a .ToString on rd["type"].  Why?  What datatype is "type" in the database.  It could be an encoding issue too.

Comment: force _type to ToLower() for the comparison and try using HttpContext.Current to do the redirect. Hope it helps.